# Bot not joining voicechannel

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I used this code to let my bot join my voicechannel, it didnt work, he keeps saying that I am not in a voicechannel, can someone help me because when I run the command I get no error or something.

```js
exports.run = async (client, message) => {
  const voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;
  if (!message.member.voiceChannel) { return message.channel.send("You are not in a voice channel, Don't force me to be lonely!"); }

  const permissions = message.member.voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.guild.me);
  if (permissions.has("CONNECT") === false) { return message.channel.send(":x: I do not have enough permissions to connect to your voice channel. I am missing the Connect permission."); }
  if (permissions.has("SPEAK") === false) { return message.channel.send("Wow. Invite me to play music for you, yet I can't speak in the channel. You're more heartless than my owner. Give me the channel permission to speak and then come back and invite me."); }

  message.member.voiceChannel.join();
  return message.channel.send(`Now tuned into: ${message.member.voiceChannel}. Ready and awaiting orders!`);
};

exports.conf = {
  enabled: true,
  runIn: ["text"],
  aliases: [],
  permLevel: 0,
  botPerms: [],
  requiredFuncs: [],
};

exports.help = {
  name: "join",
  description: "Joins the VC that you are in.",
  usage: "",
  usageDelim: "",
};
```

Comment: do `console.log(voiceChannel)` after `const voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;` and check the command

Comment: I get in console "undefined"

Comment: then do now `console.log(message.member)`

Comment: It said nothing in console

Comment: there is no problem in this code. the problem seems to be in a different place. update your question with all the related code or create a GitHub for it